# Pandas Dataframe reduce Dataframe with List comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

```
def check_LM_CapLetters(nex):
df_ja = nex.copy()
df_nein = nex.copy()
criterion_nein = df_nein["NAME2"].map(lambda x: x.endswith("_nein"))
criterion_ja = df_ja["NAME2"].map(lambda y: y.endswith("_ja"))
df_ja[criterion_ja]
df_nein[criterion_nein]
frames = [df_ja,df_nein]
df_found_small = pd.concat(frames)

return df_found_small
```

Trying to reduce my dataframe to the rows where the cell entry ends with "_ja" or "_nein".

But the output is like the two copies merged. What I want is a limitation, which only shows the rows which fulfill my criteria.

By the way... is there a more elegant and efficient way? First time dealing with list comprehensions and I'm kind of overwhelmed..

My data looks like:

Relation ID; TermID; NAME; bla;blub; TermID2; NAME2
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:
 - apply Pandas string function `.str.endswith()`
 - use complex criteria for sorting

Working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame (['aaa','bba','baa','cba', 'xbb'], columns = ['name2'])
df_small = df[(df.name2.str.endswith ('aa'))|(df.name2.str.endswith ('ba'))]
>>>
  name2
0  aaa
1  bba
2  baa
3  cba
```

Comment: I always receive an Attrivute error while doing this. Because I can not call the attribute string... Do you know why this eror occurs?

Comment: it works with my simple example - added it to the answer.  
make sure that you use your column name (previously it was 'word' in my example):
`df_small = df[(df.name2.str.endswith ('_ja'))|(df.name2.str.endswith ('_nein'))]`